# articles users comments and ajax in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

i have successfully built an app (RAILS 4) with theses tables: `users`, `comments`, and `articles` and am successful with it ... the issue is that i am creating the comments via ajax, so when I create the first comment, it creates but when i create another comment it shows the first comment with the new and the first comment , making all comment three and so on i.e it duplicates all the previous comments... but when the page is reloaded it show the actual amount of comment created  .... maybe its ma partial or my code...

ceate.js.erb

```
$('#chat').append("<%= j render(@article.comments)%>");
$("#new_comment")[0].reset();
```

my article show page is thus

```
<h1><%= @article.user.username %></h1>
<%= simple_format @article.content %>
<h2>Comments</h2>
<div id="chat">
  <%= render @article.comments %>
</div>
<h3>New Comment</h3>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

and my create action for comment is thus:

```
def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
      end
    end
 end
```

my form is thus

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build],:remote => true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 8, cols: 30 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :disable_with => 'commenting....', :class => 'submit' %>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

user model

```
  has_many :comments
  has_many :articles
```

comments model

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
```

articles model
has_many :comments

```
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  has_many :users, ->  {uniq}, through: :comments
```

how do i make this stop duplicating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create.js.erb

```
$('#chat').append("<%= j render(@article.comments)%>");
```

Should be:

```
$('#chat').html("<%= j render(@article.comments)%>");
```

Otherwise your appending ALL comments on every comment create.

Comment: damn, beaten by seconds ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is just that you're appending the full list of comments to the comment section, when you should be either a) replacing the comment section with the list of comments or b) just adding the new comment to the top/bottom.

b) is more efficient but unless efficiency has become an issue i would always just re-render the list, it's simpler and more reliable.

Try changing the first line in your create.js to

```
$('#chat').html("<%= j render(@article.comments)%>");
```